# Autosys job failing as the file it edits was open

Tags: ms-word, autosys, editmode

I have an autosys job which logs into a windows machine and performs some tasks and logs all the working into a word file on the machine.

For yesterday's run, it failed because the file in which it logs was left open by some user who logged into the machine to check the logs. The job failed because the word document(my log file that is) always opened in Edit mode only. is there a way to restrict anyone from making changes to the log file except the automated autosys job?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can add on the job log creation %autorun% which will then create a new log everytime the job runs.